# Could not get the value from Edit Text element

Tags: android

Fantastic morg. Below this code to get data from `mysql` database and displayed into the `EditText` element.There is no problem with getting data from `db` its working good using this `asyn tesk` `new checkUserPermission().execute("");`.

**Problem is** 
    I want to make some calculation from `code` and dispaly in another `Edittext`. so i need values thats why i get data from `db`.while `OnCreate()` to get the data from `db`(its working). whenever i call this `calculatePL();` method i could not get value.

**LOGCAT:**
`System.out: Empty Value`

> Why its empty or something. but above my `edittext` elements hold the
>   values.

```
  ...some declaration of variables and etc.... 
                public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.five_activity);

                        new checkUserPermission().execute(""); //call here
                        calculatePL();//call the method 
        }

    class checkUserPermission extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Five_Activity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        Dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
        userid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userID);
        uid = userid.getText().toString();
        System.out.println(uid);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> values = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", uid));

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.13:8090/stat_api/shiftClose.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(values));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is2 = entity.getContent();
            Log.i("TAG", "Connection Successful");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("TAG", e.toString());
            //Invalid Address
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is2, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
                sb2.append(line2 + "\n");
            }
            is2.close();
            result2 = sb2.toString();

            JSONObject json_data2 = new JSONObject(result2);
            code2=(json_data2.getString("code"));

            Allvalues = code2;
            String[] splited = Allvalues.split("\\s+");

            Totalkm=splited[0];
            discountamt=splited[1];
            receviedamt=splited[2];
            totalamt=splited[3];
            expen=splited[4];

            //Log.d("Splited String ", "Splited String" + totalamt+expen);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    totkm.setText(Totalkm);
                    discount.setText(discountamt);
                    recamt.setText(receviedamt);
                    totamt.setText(totalamt);
                    expenses.setText(expen);
                }
            });

            Log.i("TAG", "Result Retrieved");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("TAG", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        // Close progress dialog
        Dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public void calculatePL(){
        try {
            String a_value =totamt.getText().toString().trim();
            System.out.println(a_value);

        }catch(NumberFormatException numberEx)
        {
            System.out.println(numberEx);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `setText()` should not be done inside `doInBackground()` method. That you should do in `onPostExecute()`. All the UI related changes should be made inside `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: oh okay bro i will change  and test with `onPostExecute()` @PrathameshToradmal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `protected void onPostExecute` in your asyncTask and call `calculatePl()`  here. And you should set `Edittext`'s text in `onPostExecute` too, because this method is main thread and you don't need to use `runOnUIThread`.

EDIT with example code:

```
class checkUserPermission extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Five_Activity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            Dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
            userid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userID);
            uid = userid.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(uid);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> values = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", uid));

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.13:8090/stat_api/shiftClose.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(values));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is2 = entity.getContent();
                Log.i("TAG", "Connection Successful");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("TAG", e.toString());
                //Invalid Address
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is2, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb2.append(line2 + "\n");
                }
                is2.close();
                result2 = sb2.toString();

                JSONObject json_data2 = new JSONObject(result2);
                code2=(json_data2.getString("code"));

                Allvalues = code2;


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("TAG", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Allvalues;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){

            String[] splited = result.split("\\s+");

            Totalkm=splited[0];
            discountamt=splited[1];
            receviedamt=splited[2];
            totalamt=splited[3];
            expen=splited[4];


            totkm.setText(Totalkm);
            discount.setText(discountamt);
            recamt.setText(receviedamt);
            totamt.setText(totalamt);
            expenses.setText(expen);
            // Close progress dialog
            Dialog.dismiss();
            calculatePL();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @karthi `onPostExecute` method is called then `doInBackground` is finished. So you are guaranteed that you are calling `calculatePl()` after you get your data from server. With current code you provided you are calling calculatePL() before you get your data from server thats why it returns empty value.

Comment: yes i not sure i get the values from db before calculatePl() execute (I think before compleate `checkUserPermission` the `calculatePI()` runned  ). this is the problem but how to fix ? i dont know @Vygintas sir

Comment: @karthi i updated my answer with example maybe this will help

Comment: yes its working i just put inside of `onPostExecute` only setTest() and `calculatePI()` methods. Thanks for your **HELP**

Answer (score 1):

Your `checkUserPermission` executes in background. And immediately you are calling `calculatePL()` so your main thread is not waiting for `checkUserPermission` execution to complete.

What you need to do is, make wait your main thread so that after full execution of `checkUserPermission` `calculatePL()` will get called. You can achieve it by adding `ProgressDialog`. Show the `ProgressDialog` in `onPreExecute()` and dismiss it in `onPostExecute()`

Hope it will do your job.

Comment: can you update new code in your question so that I can see what you have done?

Comment: `setText()` should not be done inside `doInBackground()` method. That you should do in `onPostExecute()`. All the UI related changes should be made inside `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `totamt` is declared as a global. Try logging the value of `totamt` or an object of the same. Finally check where you have declared it.

Comment: Have you created the object?

Comment: Before calling the function like your userid? (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userID);

Comment: hmm. i think noooo

Comment: Thats the issue

Comment: Its not a problem. If it was a problem he would get Null Pointer Exception

Comment: Thats why there is no Null Pointer

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.five_activity);
//Add here
                        new checkUserPermission().execute(""); //call here
                        calculatePL();//call the method 
        }

Comment: @Ajay_Arya Sir, you are wrong. You still get exeptions

Comment: Exception is not caught since the code contains only NumberFormatException.

Comment: Yes, its not cought, but its thrown and application would get fatal error